# How to do Linq to object

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I am having a list of objects as follows

```
  List<object> creditOptions = new List<object>();
  creditOptions = (List<object>)pGateways;
```

The data filled in creditOptions is coming from a server in json format and it keeps on changing. It has some data as follows

```
{
"options": [
    {
        "id": "QP",
        "order-index": "1",
        "name": "Quick Pay",
        "urls": [
            {
                "Key": "sample",
                "Value": "sample"
            },
            {
                "Key": "sample",
                "Value": "sample"
            },
            {
                "Key": "sample",
                "Value": "sample"
            }
        ],
        "is_active": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "CC",
        "order-index": "0",
        "name": "sample",
        "card-type": [
            {
                "name": "sample",
                "item-code": "sample",
                "bank_id": "sample"
            },
            {
                "name": "sample",
                "item-code": "sample",
                "bank_id": "sample"
            }
        ],
        "makePaymentCreditUrl": "sample",
        "is_active": 1
    }
]
```

}

Now what i want to do is i want to fire a linq query on creditOptions list to takeout the data based on "id".Is this possible using linq on a List.

I am using the following line of code to deserialize json object

```
Dictionary<string, object> pGateways = (Dictionary<string,object>)Json.JsonParser.FromJson(response);
```

MetaData of JsonParser is

```
public class JsonParser
{
    public JsonParser();

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json);
    public static object Deserialize(string json, Type type);
    public static IDictionary<string, object> FromJson(string json);
    public static IDictionary<string, object> FromJson(string json, out JsonToken type);
    public static string Serialize<T>(T instance);
    public static string ToJson(IDictionary<string, object> bag);
}
```

This is a windows phone 8 project.

Comment: You need a concrete type instead of `object` , de-serialize your JSON to a custom object and then you can query, or may be `dynamic` keyword could help, but not sure about that one.

Comment: First question: How are you parsing the JSON? The answer to that question will change the answers we can give. (Hint: a short but complete example would be really helpful.)

Comment: @Habib cannot have a concrete type as the data comes from external server and we dont have control over it.

Comment: @vidyasagar2012, so data is always different ? If that is the case , what makes you think that you will get `ID` back each time ?

Comment: @Habib actually what i mean is data is not different but sometimes new fields are added sometimes some fields are taken out....that's the reason why we cant have a concrete type.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have edited my question which shows you the way i am parsing json

Comment: @Habib now can you please guide me through...

Comment: No, you haven't shown how you're parsing the JSON. You've talked about a JsonParser class, but told us nothing about where it's coming from. In fact, I remember you doing *exactly* this a few days ago, with me asking exactly the same questions. Please *learn* from past experiences. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet i have mentioned it that the json is coming from server...i am parsing it using the JsonParser.FromJson method only....can u give me an example as what exactly you want from me...

Comment: I want you to say where the `JsonParser` class comes from, so we can find out whether it handles `dynamic` etc. Just the same as I asked you on the last question. (For example, I usually use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)...)

Comment: @JonSkeet It comes from Json.WindowsPhone.dll

Comment: And where did you get that from? Given the name, I assume it's not just a standard out-of-the-box library. Please include a link in the question. (You might also want to consider using Json.NET, which would make this really simple...)

Answer (score 0):

Linq can work with anything implementing IEnumerable so that shouldn't be a problem.

However in the linq query you need to specify a property on the object which is part of the class definition and your id is not part of object. Therefore you need have a type that has those properties.

You need to parse the json string into something which at least have a property named Id. From the example given all json objects have id, order-index and name. You could try creating interface with those  properties and instead of using object you could use the interface when parsing. Something like `Dictionary<string, YourInterface> pGateways ...`

Then you can use the properties in the linq query something like `var result = (from x in pGateways where x.id == "myid" select x);` or similar.

Comment: will try your solution

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to get the rest of the stuff from the json object, but at least it should take care of linq selection issues. Hope it helps.